# elasticsearch update by query not allow update value with special characters

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have data having special characters in fields ! while I am add those data then it inserted in Elasticsearch properly! but at time of update it gives error!

```
POST index_name/_update_by_query
{
"script": {
   "source": "ctx._source.key1='vakey22'",
   "lang": "painless"
 },
 "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term":{"condtion1":"value1"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then it works perfect but when we try to add any special character then it gives error

```
POST index_name/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.key1='vak\ey22'",
      "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term":{"condtion1":"value1"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

getting following error while adding any special characters

[script_exception] compile error, with { script_stack={ 0="...  ctx._source.key1=''; ctx._source.key2 ..." & 1="                             ^---- HERE" } & script=" ctx._source.key3='0'

how can we resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is since you are posting JSON that you need to escape your escape character (which would be `\`). So to escape special characters this would be `\\` and to get an actual backslash you should write `\\\\`. This github [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22372) discusses something similar, albeit a bit in a different context. So your query would be like this:

```
POST index_name/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.key1='vak\\\\ey22'",
      "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term":{"condtion1":"value1"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help! I have used following code using it we no need to add backslashes "script": { "source": "ctx._source.key1 = params.key1;", "lang": "painless", "params": { "key1": "vak\ey22" } } NOTE : when there is double quote in value then only we need to add backslashes